# How to Group columns in front end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2-jquery

Table has to be displayed in front end. Following is the code.

```
<logic:present name="searchStudent">
    <table class=" tblSearchResult" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <caption><b><bean:message key="label.student.details.display"/></b></caption>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><b><bean:message key="label.student.class.code"/></b></td>
        <td align="center"><b><bean:message key="label.student.name.code"/></b></td>
        <td align="center"><b><bean:message key="label.student.section.code"/></b></td>
        <td align="center"><b><bean:message key="label.edit" /></b></td>
        <td align="center"><b><bean:message key="label.delete" /></b></td>
    </tr>
    <logic:iterate name="searchStudent" id="row">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <bean:write name="row" property="sclass" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <bean:write name="row" property="sname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <bean:write name="row" property="section" />
        </td>
            
        <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><input
                onclick="clearMessage();updateStudent(this);"
                type="image"
                src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/pen_edit_thick.png"
                class="imgEditPen"
                title="<bean:message key="button.tooltip.edit"/>"></td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><input
                onclick="clearMessage();deleteStudent();"
                type="image"
                src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/icon_delete.gif"
                class="imgEditPen"
                title="<bean:message key="button.tooltip.remove"/>"></td>
        
    </tr>
    </logic:iterate>
    </table>
</logic:present>
```

It has three columns in table namely class,student name and section. Since class is same for some student it has to spanned across students having same class. Following is the sample output.

[image]

Data is fetched from Backend.

Comment: What have you tried and what issues are you having?

Comment: Tried adding rowspan but that doesnt work.Since rows are fetched from backend the UI is not proper..Based on number of students in the same class it has to span automatically in UI.

Comment: Tried using Hashmap in the form.But not rendered properly.

Comment: If there are two or more identical cells with one another in a column, then this cells should be automatically joined using the HTML attribute rowspan

I am not able to find a solution for dynamically create a table with joined cells in the same column.

Answer (score 1):

**Colspan Attribute** can merge columns in a table.

```
<td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
```

**Example**

```
     <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Result**

[image]

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

**Rowspan Attribute:**

```
 <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Comment: Can use these attributes when we are sure for how many rows the spanning has to be done.I don't know how many students belongs to same class. Data is being fetched from backend. Based on number of students in the same class it has to span automatically in UI.

Comment: Hi Padamja, you can dynamically create attitude on the fly using createAttribute(), example is here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createattribute.asp

Comment: No..Can u pls tell me how to solve it using createAttribute @HGG-Dev

Comment: If there are two or more identical cells with one another in a column, then this cells should be automatically joined using the HTML attribute rowspan

I am not able to find a solution for dynamically create a table with joined cells in the same column.